# Constant lockups in xpage designer?

Tags: xpages

Our group experiences constant lockups of the designer. We might be good for an hour or two then Notes just locks up.  It requires that you crash the client and restart but then you are back to where you were in a couple of hours.

We are running 8.5.3 Revision 20110916.0921 (Release 8.5.3) 
Windows XP (yes XP)
We all have Dell laptops with 3G of ram

Is there any way to fix this with perhaps a configuration setting or is it a bug?

Comment: run NSD and look for thread common to all machines. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/06262009085854amwebh8v.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the JVM is running low in memory? Please change jvm.properties. It is located at /framework/rcp/deploy/jvm.properties.

If the file has never been edited by you, it should have the following as values:

```
vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx256m
vmarg.Xms=-Xms48m
vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca8k
```

Please change it to the following value:

```
vmarg.Xmx=-Xmx1024m
vmarg.Xms=-Xms512m
vmarg.Xmca=-Xmca512k
```

Comment: What is the Xmca setting? Is that the default increment? Also, is it possible to push that out via a policy?

Comment: If those are the best config settings for a 3G machine, does doubling those specs for a 6G machine work the same way?

Comment: I must have changed these before but they weren't as high as you recommend so I bumped them up.

Comment: Wouldn't bumping up these numbers just make the issues less frequent?  Issue seems to get worse the longer I use it.  So I would think increasing the numbers might do just that.

Comment: You are correct in stating that bumping them up might make the issues less frequent :-)
However, there are certain features in Designer that do require more than 256mb of memory, or at least require very close to 256mb; as a result once the jvm allocates close to that amount, and then receives further requests for more memory the jvm has to spend a lot of time garbage collecting. Increasing the maximum amount of memory means that less time is spent in GC, and as editors etc are closed then large amounts of memory are released. We've fixed many of these memory issues the the latest release

Comment: I would not recommend doubling them for a 6GB machine, if designer is running out of memory or performing poorly with 1gb of memory then there are bigger issues at play.
@PaulStephenWithers I am not aware of these being editable via policy [but it is a good point!]
Xmca refers to the size of the blocks the JVM uses to increase memory.

Comment: Not sure if this one did it or turning off the auto build but lockups appear to be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you have excluded .ntf/.nsf/.jar files from Antivirus on-access scanner/real-time scan. As well consider disabling indexing of drive in Windows. See more info here http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/ImprovingNotesClientPerformanceStabilityFinal.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but if you have enabled "Build automatically" I suggest you turn this off in the menue "Project - Build auomatically". 
I also use WinXP with 8.5.3 and ExtLib and a rather similar Hardware spec.

Comment: Yes I have it turned on.  I am going to try and turn it off and see if that does it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can go higher than 1024 but maybe Dan can verify..